# Theory/Magic behind creating API

Tags: php, api

Im a newbie PHP programmer and I have a few questions about creating a REST based API service.

Basically, its going to be a github open source project which is going to scrape various data off the web and offer it as an API in XML. Now here are my questions in terms of how should I or how can I do this.

1) **Since there isnt a robust/same pattern for getting various data through scraping, what is the best way to actually output the xml?** 
I mean the PHP file would have various lines of extracting data from various points in the code and the file would be a lot of lines. Is it a good idea to type the code to output the result in there?

2) **Is there a way to organize the scraping code in a sort of class?** 
I cant think of a way that would work besides linear approach where not even a function is created and you just apply functions (in general).

3) **If theres a way to do that ^^ , how can it you output it?** 
Is there any other approach besides using another file and getting the contents from the main file and displaying the code through the secondary file.

4) **If I were to offer the API in XML and JSON, is there a way to port from one result to another or will I have to manually create the fields in json or xml and place the content in there?**

I might have more questions that might arise after these have been answered but I hope I get everything cleared up. Also, this is assuming that the results are not fetched from a DB so the data has to be scraped/tabulated on every request. (even though caching will be implemented later)

Thanks

Comment: I can't answer this question, but I can offer advise.  I would split your 4 questions into four Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: This question is very broad - a lot of the answers to these sort of questions, however, are arbitrary to design. It's __your__ API, design it in a way you feel is most appropriate and would be most useful to your userbase.

Comment: @RageD I agree! but as an inexperienced developer, I couldnt come across the concepts of better design. I have the script done and for one of them the code for scraping is right above the code that I am using to output the data in xml. I just wanted to know if theres a better way of doing this

Comment: XML and JSON are pretty standard formats for this - both could be used effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is probably more appropriate on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Not to be rude, but a **newbie programmer developing an API is like a first-year med student offering to do open-heart transplants for free**. I understand that you believe that you can program, but if you intend to release publicly accessible code, you probably need more experience. Otherwise guys like me will muck through it and file bug reports ridiculing your code.

That said, if you want theory of good API design you should probably check out [Head First Object Oriented Analysis and Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008678). You'll want to focus on these key concepts

1. Program to an Interface, not an Implementation
2. Encapsulate what varies

...and follow other [good design principles](http://mmiika.wordpress.com/oo-design-principles/vv).

...honestly, there's a lot to cover to good interface and good systems design. You can use this as a learning exercise, but let people know they shouldn't rely on your code. Though they should know that screen scraping is far more brittle and instable than web service API requests anyway, but many don't.

That said, to provide some initial guidance:

1. Yes, use OOP. Encapsulate the part that actually does the scraping (presumably using cURL) in a class. This will allow you to switch scraping engines transparently to the end user. Encapsulate your outputs in classes, which will allow for easy extension (i.e. if JSON output is in a Single Responsibility class and XML Output is in another, I can add RSS Output easily by making a new class without breaking your old code)
2. Think about the contracts your code must live up to. That will drive the interface. If you are scraping a particular type of data (say, sports scores for a given day), those should drive the types of operations available (i.e. function getSportsScoresForDate(date toGet))
3. Start with your most abstract/general operations at a top level interface, then use other interfaces that extend that interface. This allows users to have interfaces at different levels of granularity (i.e. class SensorDataInterface has a method getData(). HeartRateMonitorInterface extends SensorDataInterface and adds getDataForTimeInterval())

Comment: @Visionary-Software-Solutions Try to look at this [link](https://github.com/kartiktalwar/Web-Data/blob/master/api/TopSongs.php) My question is that is it a good idea to have xml tags getting echoed withing the script or is there a better way to organize the content from the output..

Comment: First Problem: DOM parsing via regex is ugly and brittle (if I change my markup to <a title="gotcha!" href=""> you're super-pwned). I highly recommend using the DOM class. If you're doing XML parsing, there are classes built in to XPATH/XQuery this stuff for you. Use them.

Comment: Next problem: So if I want to change TopSongs.php to output JSON instead of XML, what's my plan? Do I change that script? What if I want both? Do I need to clone TopSongs.php and call it TopSongsJSON.php? What if I want to add a $yearMade to the album info in the output across both? Do I need to go in and modify 2 scripts now? This looks like you're combining FrontController with a parser. Encapsulate your AlbumInfo (the variables set in the for loop) as a Domain Model. A separate parser class should handle getting the results of scraping and passing those to the domain model.

Comment: Then the TopSongs.php becomes just a front controller, that creates a Scraper, sets the URL, calls a parser to process the results and exposes the desired attributes as properties. You create a new Song (I realized that would be a better name than AlbumInfo as I stared at the code) object from the parser's exposed attributes. Then you call a method that handles the responsibility of rendering the domain object. For simplicity, you may want to add it to the domain object. For example: echo song->renderAsXML()